# Inverse is not connected

Tags: continuity, closed-form, connectedness

Let $f:[a, b] \rightarrow[a, b]$ be continuous. Provide a counterexample for the following statement:

The inverse image $f^{-1}([c, d])$ is connected for any $[c, d] \subset[a, b]$.

One of the ideas that I could think of is to give an example for which inverse image $f^{-1}([c, d])$ would be the union of two closed intervals, concluding the disconnectedness of it. However, after trying a lot of examples, I could not come up with a solid example for this case.

Note: The values $a,b$ are fixed.

Comment: Could you please exemplify what you mean by preimage? More details would be strongly appreciated!

Comment: Does anyone have ideas regarding this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f:[-1,1]\to[-1,1]$ be given by $f(x)=x^2$. Now $[1/4,1]\subset[-1,1]$ is a connected subset, and $f^{-1}([1/4,1])=[-1,\frac{-1}{2}]\cup[\frac{1}{2},1]$ which is a disconnected subset of $[-1,1]$.

The same idea here works for any $[a,b]$ by shifting/scaling $f$ as desired (as noted in the comments).

Comment: the domain should not be modified!

Comment: what do you mean by that

Comment: You had modified the function $f$'s domain and range - this is not allowed! You should work exclusively with $a,b$!

Comment: I didn't "modify" anything though. This is just a specific example for some $a,b$

Comment: I again note that the counterexample should be dependent on $a,b$. Provide the example for $f$ using the given values $a,b$ without changing $f$'s given domain $[a,b]$!

Comment: If you really want to prove it for *any* a, b rather than some *arbitrary* a, b, then just take the specific counterexample here and adjust it for the specific values you want (i.e. shift and scale the parabola until it fits in the required interval in both directions).

Comment: @Snowflake: the adjustments to Michael's answer to replace the open interval $(0, 1)$ by a closed interval are trivial.

Comment: @RobArthan The main topic here is to illustrate the desired answer for the posted problem, not complaining about the little issues of choosing $c,d$

Comment: @Snowflake: I'm not sure what more you want. You can adjust my answer to work for any $[a,b]$.

Comment: @snowflake: Why do you assume $a.b$ are given. but $f$ is not? My interpretation of the problem statement is that $f,a,b,c,d$ can be specified by the counterexample producer.

Comment: @Snowflake: you have been given all the mathematical input you need to solve your question. Please stop your pointless bleating.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f: [-2\pi, 2\pi] \to [-2\pi, 2\pi]$, $f(x)=\sin (x)$.

Notice that $[0,1] \subset [-2\pi, 2\pi]$, try to compute $f^{-1}([0,1])$ to illustrate that it is a counterexample.

Comment: How about general domain $[a,b]$? Deeply appreciate your counterexample, but it should be applicable to all $[a,b]$ though

Comment: First, first of all, this is not what is being asked in the quesiton. But if you insist, if $a < b$, try to draw a square, $[a, b] \times [a,b]$, try to sketch such a graph.